# Select one pin from 16 bits wide register, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, bit

**[Inputs]:**

Address: 0x001c, 16 bits wide.

Reset: 0x0

This is a bit-field register for PINs 16..31.

**[Question]:** How could I select PIN 17?

**[My solution]:** Is that the right way of doing it:

```
def select_pin(pin):
    lowstate = 0x0000
    highstate = 0x001c
    pin_hex = int(str(pin), 16)
    responsive = highstate-pin_hex
    inverted = hex(responsive ^ 0xFFFF)
    print(inverted)

select_pin(17)
```

To be honest I have a theoretical gap about this area, I'm not even sure how to formulate my question to find some info about it in Google, any help would much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to get the pin value (*0* or *1*) out of that value? And each pin is a bit in it? And in this case bit 17 is 0?

Comment: @CristiFati, thank you for your quick response. I want it to be 1. I guess to do so I don't need the last part of the code "inverted = hex(responsive ^ 0xFFFF)". Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the (register) value bits represent the pin values, where each pin number represents the *bit* index from *LSB* -> *MSB* (right to left), all you have to do is a simple ***bitwise and*** between:

- The value
- A mask which has **only one *bit* set** (in the position of the required pin), while all the others are reset

to extract the *bit* (pin) value that you're interested in:

> ```py
> >>> reg = 0x001C0000  # Hi Word, Lo Word
> >>>
> >>> reg_bin_repr = "{0:032b}".format(0x001C0000)  # For visualization purposes only
> >>> reg_bin_repr
> '00000000000111000000000000000000'
> >>>
> >>> for idx, val in enumerate(reversed(reg_bin_repr)):  # Each bit with its value (right -> left)
> ...     print("Bit (pin) {0:02d}: {1:s}".format(idx, val))
> ...
> Bit (pin) 00: 0
> Bit (pin) 01: 0
> Bit (pin) 02: 0
> Bit (pin) 03: 0
> Bit (pin) 04: 0
> Bit (pin) 05: 0
> Bit (pin) 06: 0
> Bit (pin) 07: 0
> Bit (pin) 08: 0
> Bit (pin) 09: 0
> Bit (pin) 10: 0
> Bit (pin) 11: 0
> Bit (pin) 12: 0
> Bit (pin) 13: 0
> Bit (pin) 14: 0
> Bit (pin) 15: 0
> Bit (pin) 16: 0
> Bit (pin) 17: 0
> Bit (pin) 18: 1
> Bit (pin) 19: 1
> Bit (pin) 20: 1
> Bit (pin) 21: 0
> Bit (pin) 22: 0
> Bit (pin) 23: 0
> Bit (pin) 24: 0
> Bit (pin) 25: 0
> Bit (pin) 26: 0
> Bit (pin) 27: 0
> Bit (pin) 28: 0
> Bit (pin) 29: 0
> Bit (pin) 30: 0
> Bit (pin) 31: 0
> >>>
> >>> # And the function
> >>> def pin_value(register_value, pin_number):
> ...     return 1 if register_value & (1 << pin_number) else 0
> ...
> >>>
> >>> pin_value(reg, 17)
> 0
> >>> pin_value(reg, 18)
> 1
> ```

As a side note, when working with numbers, you don't have to convert them to the same base, the value doesn't change when converting it to a different base, only its representation does:

> ```py
> >>> i0 = 1
> >>> i1 = 0x19
> >>>
> >>> i0 + i1
> 26
> >>> i1
> 25
> >>> hex(i1)
> '0x19'
> >>> int(hex(i1), 16)
> 25
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Bitmasks are simply `2**pin` in integernotation.

If you have an "register" binary of

```
# alternating increasing amounts of 0/1
reg = int("10110011100011110000111110000010",2)  # 4294967295

def get_pin(value, pin):
    return 1 if (value & 2**pin) > 0 else 0 

for p in range(33):
    print(f"{2**p:>10} is {get_pin(reg,p)}")

         1 is 0
         2 is 1
         4 is 0
         8 is 0
        16 is 0
        32 is 0
        64 is 0
       128 is 1
       256 is 1
       512 is 1
      1024 is 1
      2048 is 1
      4096 is 0
      8192 is 0
     16384 is 0
     32768 is 0
     65536 is 1
    131072 is 1
    262144 is 1
    524288 is 1
   1048576 is 0
   2097152 is 0
   4194304 is 0
   8388608 is 1
  16777216 is 1
  33554432 is 1
  67108864 is 0
 134217728 is 0
 268435456 is 1
 536870912 is 1
1073741824 is 0
2147483648 is 1
```